# Why don't my promisify and jwt return values or errors?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, express-jwt, node-promisify

```
if(req.cookies.token_name) {
    try {
        const decoded = await promisify(jwt.verifiy)(req.cookies.token_name, 
        process.env.jwtsecret);
        console.log(decoded);
    } 
    
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

This is the bit I'm having problems with. It doesn't log the decoded variable but it also doesn't give any errors. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are you calling in an asynchronous context? On a separate topic, you should use `console.error` when printing error data. On linux stdout is buffering and your process may exit (crash) before writing, stderr is non-buffering and will write immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a typo in your function name, although it's hard to tell without seeing your import/require statements. `verifiy` should be `verify`.

```
const decoded = await promisify(jwt.verify)(req.cookies.token_name, ...);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply I was trying different things for almost 30 min before giving up. From now on I will speelcheck before I post here. Thank you

Comment: if this solved your problem, will you accept this answer? :)

Comment: Of coure. I'm fairly new to this :)